# Change in number density of a column of gas in a gravitational field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

Suppose I have column of gas that starts from height $z=0$, the Gravitational potential energy at any point is given by $mgz$. Now I want to calculate the number density of such a column of gas given that it is in Thermal and Chemical equilibrium with a bath.

Quite naturally, I model it as a Grand Canonical Ensemble Ideal Gas. It is well known that the partition function for such a system is given by $$\mathbb{Q}(T,\mu,V)=\exp[e^{\beta\mu}\frac{V}{\lambda^{3}}]$$ *[Reference - Kardar, Statistical Mechanics of Particles, pg 119-120]*

Where now, $\mu$ is given by $\mu(z)=\mu_{0}+mgz$, notice that it agrees with the notion that particles tend to move from region of higher $\mu$ to region of lower $\mu$. Now in order to find density, we can find the mean number of particles divided by volume.

We can find out the average number of particles using the relation $$\bar{N}=\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}{\rm Ln[\mathbb{Q}]}$$. Doing this leads us to the expression $$\bar{N}\propto e^{\frac{mgz}{kT}}$$. Which signifies, that the particle density is **increasing** on increasing height. But as we know, this seems to be improbable, and also we know that instead the relation should look like
$$\bar{N}\propto e^{\frac{-mgz}{kT}}$$.

Why is my process giving apparently unphysical results?

Comment: I think the premise of this problem is flawed.  By definition of putting a system in chemical equilibrium with a reservoir at some fixed chemical potential, we assume that $\mu$ is fixed in our system.  Particles will be exchanged with the reservoir in order to maintain $\mu$.  I don't think it makes sense to apply the GCE here, since it imposes fixed $\mu$, but you expressly allow $\mu$ to vary spatially.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and indeed I realise it's wrong to assume it to be a GCE. Can you suggest me a proper method using statistical mechanics that can predict the correct relation without getting into single particle dynamics?